# How to format/decode service logs from Docker API

Tags: express, axios, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get logs from the Docker API [at this endpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ServiceLogs). I'm just trying to get the logs returned as a string, not using the websocket option. It mostly works, but the string contains strange characters that I'm not sure what to do with.

I'm using Axios, with Express, like so:

```
let result = await AXIOS.get(`http://${managerNodeIPAddress}/services/${idForLogs}/logs?stdout=true&stderr=true`);
```

and if I `console.log(result)`, the `data` property looks like this:

```
  data: '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#Example app listening on port 5000\n' +
    '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1F[16/4/2022-21:05:02] GET/: 200\n' +
    '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1F[16/4/2022-21:05:43] GET/: 200\n' +
    '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1F[16/4/2022-21:05:44] GET/: 200\n' +
    '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1F[16/4/2022-21:06:33] GET/: 200\n' +
// ...
```

and if I `console.log(result.data)`, it looks like this:

```
<Buffer 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 45 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 20 61 70 70 20 6c 69 73 74 65 6e 69 6e 67 20 6f 6e 20 70 6f 72 74 20 35 30 30 30 0a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 972 more bytes>
```

If I send along this response, and try to view it response in Postman, or elsewhere, the viewer doesn't know what to do with the initial `\x01`-type strings:

[image]

I gather that they are escaped binary, or something along those lines, and I need to change something about my request headers, or parse the axios response, in a particular way, to deal with this. I would be happy either

1. decoding those characters into whatever they are supposed to be (I've tried "decoding" the buffer, using `toString('utf-8)`, etc, but that doesn't seem to get rid of the characters, so they still show up strange when passed along and viewed in certain contexts.). OR,
2. getting rid of those characters entirely (I tried to do the later with the `replace` method, but it isn't working for some reason).

I've never dealt with this before, so the world of encoding/decoding things like this feels a bit mysterious, and I would appreciate any pointers anyone might have.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to figure this out. As I understand things now, the 00 and 01 are (or represent?) hex bytes, which [correspond to](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Eharry/compilers/ASCIIChart.pdf) the ASCII characters SOH (start of header) and NUL (null). The mac terminal doesn't have trouble interpreting them, but it appears some other applications do. I was able to get rid of them by filtering the buffer array, like so:

```
let logs = result.data.filter(byte => byte !== 01 && byte !== 00).toString();
```

I was honestly a little surprised this worked, but it seems to have. It doesn't affect how the logs look in the terminal, and they look fine in Postman now.

Comment: Look like this is a known issue in docker, your solution is one of the way to get around it https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/140

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this applies to the `/containers/{id}/logs` endpoint, but I think it's likely the format is reused.)

I found that `docker logs` outputs correctly, as does `cat`-ing the JSON, but fetching via the Engine API returns similarly "malformed" data. In my case, I was noticing an additional non-null character (e.g. hex `01 00 00 00  00 00 00 59`)

It seems like each chunk (line?) is preceded by the following 8 byte header sequence:

`SOH NUL NUL NUL A B C D` where ABCD is a big-endian 32-bit integer representing the length.

I've inferred this from the following section of `docker-py` library code (comments mine):

```py
# Within a while loop
# STREAM_HEADER_SIZE_BYTES is 8
header = response.raw.read(STREAM_HEADER_SIZE_BYTES)
if not header:
    break
# `>`=big endian, `B`=unsigned char (SOH/0x01)
# `x`=padding, `L`=long aka unsigned int32
# _ is getting SOH, length is getting the chunk size
_, length = struct.unpack('>BxxxL', header)
if not length:
    continue
# Read remainder of chunk
data = response.raw.read(length)
if not data:
    break
yield data
```

Sources: [`struct` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), [`docker-py` source (GitHub)](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/main/docker/api/client.py#L385)